# flutter onTap error onTap stopped working after adding if statement

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

i'm getting null error in flutter button stopped working after added if statement inside the ontap here is my flutter code

```
import 'package:efood_multivendor/controller/product_controller.dart';
import 'package:efood_multivendor/util/dimensions.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get_core/src/get_main.dart';
import 'package:get/get_instance/src/extension_instance.dart';
import 'package:get/get_utils/src/extensions/internacionalization.dart';

import 'custom_snackbar.dart';

class QuantityButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isIncrement;
  final Function onTap;
  final int quantity;
  final int stock;
  QuantityButton(
      {@required this.isIncrement,
      @required this.onTap,
      @required this.quantity,
      @required this.stock});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
       onTap : onTap({
        if (!isIncrement && quantity > 1) {
          Get.find<ProductController>().setQuantity(false),
        } else if (isIncrement) {
          if (quantity < stock) {
            Get.find<ProductController>().setQuantity(true),
          } else {
            showCustomSnackBar('out_of_stock'.tr),
          }
        }
      }),
      child: Container(
        height: 22,
        width: 22,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_SMALL),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          border: Border.all(
              width: 1,
              color: isIncrement
                  ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                  : Theme.of(context).disabledColor),
          color: isIncrement
              ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
              : Theme.of(context).disabledColor.withOpacity(0.2),
        ),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Icon(
          isIncrement ? Icons.add : Icons.remove,
          size: 15,
          color: isIncrement
              ? Theme.of(context).cardColor
              : Theme.of(context).disabledColor,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

error : if i try removing if statement and add `onTap:onTap` it is working i'm getting `Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: '<Unexpected Null Value>'` error still button not working
and also tried this method but still showing the same and onTap not working

````
       onTap : (){
        if (!isIncrement && quantity > 1) {
          Get.find<ProductController>().setQuantity(false);
        } else if (isIncrement) {
          if (quantity < stock) {
            Get.find<ProductController>().setQuantity(true);
          } else {
            showCustomSnackBar('out_of_stock'.tr);
          }
} ```
````

Comment: Can you briefly explain what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: onTap function not working

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `onTap` parameter requires a `VoidCallback` object and you declare it in two ways:

Throwaway function. Specific for the widget and not callable by other.

```
onTap : (){
    ... your code ...
  }
```

or declaring a new function in this way

```
void yourFunction(){
    ... your code ...
  }
```

and use that function in your button

```
onTap : yourFunction
```

This second way allow you to call the function from different Widget